# In XQuery, how do I recursively filter descendants based on a given predicate?

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, xquery, predicate

Given this XML snippet:

```
<root> <!-- $root points here -->
  <!-- ... -->
  <A visible="true">
    <B visible="false">
      <C visible="true"/> <!-- but effectively false! -->
    </B>
    <D visible="true">
      <E visible="true" />
      <F visible="false" />
    </D>
  </A>
  <!-- ... -->
</root>
```

running the query `$root//A` will give me `A` and all its descendants. So far so good.

What I want instead is to filter the descendants of `A` by a predicate, say `[@visible=true]`. I expect the query to return

```
  <A visible="true">
    <D visible="true">
      <E visible="true" />
    </D>
  </A>
```

instead, ie. filter out all child elements that don't match the predicate (or whose parents don't match it).

Think a GUI system that is described in XML like above and where I filter the tree for visible elements when rendering it.

I think this would be trivial with XSLT, but I'm bound to use XQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in XQuery without too much effort either. Just have a function recursively rewrite the qualified nodes, while applying the filter:

```
declare function local:rewrite($node as node()) as node()?
{
    typeswitch ($node)
    case element() return
        if (local:filter($node)) then
            element {node-name($node)}
            {
                $node/@*,
                for $child in $node/node() return local:rewrite($child)
            }
        else
            ()
    default return
        $node
};

declare function local:filter($node as element()) as xs:boolean
{
    $node/@visible
};
```

Then use a path expression to select A and apply the function to the result:

```
for $a in $root//A return local:rewrite($a)
```

The function employs a common pattern for using XQuery to handle said-to-be XSLT tasks. In fact I think it is very much acceptable to do it this way, too. For my part, I appreciate the benefit of not having to leave XQuery notation here...

Comment: Maybe you do realize that by writing such code every time you need to perform a transformation, you are manually describing the actions done automatically and behind the scene by every XSLT processor? I personally appreciate that an XSLT processor saves the need for me to write this manually and waste my time. More time for sleep this way ... :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I know this is trivial in XSLT, I even said so in the question, but XSLT isn't the XML query language, and until XSLT features are added to XQuery (such as Ranon has described with XQuery Update, which I unfortunately can't use because the processor in Qt doesn't yet support it), saying XSLT is better for this task is fruitless repetition of obvious facts. If you have a better option than writing a function, I'll be more than happy to accept it when you post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Gunther: I had to wrap the `$node/@visible` into `xs:boolean` and inline `local:filter()` into `local:rewrite()`. If I don't wrap, it also matches elements with `visible="false"`; if I don't inline, I get an error `XPTY0004: Required cardinality is exactly one; got cardinality one or more("+").` The first I somewhat understand, but the cardinality error is opaque to me. Can you shed some light?

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz: the function's return type is `xs:boolean` without an occurrence indicator, thus it must return exactly one boolean value. When passing an element without a `visible` attribute, the function will return `xs:boolean(())`, which evaluates to empty sequence, and does not qualify as one boolean. This does not present a problem when inlining, because then the "effective boolean value" of that empty sequence will be evaluated, and it is `false()`. Thus the function as I wrote it did not take into account that there may be elements without a `visible` attribute. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz: When inlining, but without constructing an `xs:boolean`, the "effective boolean value" is calculated for a single attribute. This evaluates to `true()`, regardless of the attribute's value. Sorry for the confusion. See [http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-ebv] and [http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-constructor-functions] for detailed rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [XQuery Update](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Update#transform) and deleting all invisible ones:

```
copy $c:=$root
modify delete node $c//*[@visible="false"]
return $c
```

Comment: A very concise approach. I love it. Unfortunately, the XQuery processor I'm using (QXmlQuery from Qt) doesn't yet support it :(